# unexpected exit of loop with ifstream getline

Tags: c++, file-io, while-loop, ifstream, getline

please look at the below code:

```
std::string s;
while(std::getline(m_File,s))
{
    std::cout<<"running\n";
    std::string upper(s);
    std::transform(upper.begin(),upper.end(),upper.begin(),toupper);


    if(upper.find("*NODE") != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::cout<<"start reading nodes\n";
        readnodes();

    }
    std::cout<<"\n open? "<<m_File.is_open()<<"\n";

}
```

I'm trying to extract data from the below input file.(**INPUT FILE**)

```
 *NODE
 1 ,1.0,2.0
 2, 2.6,3.4
 3, 3.4, 5.6
 *NODE
 4, 4, 5
 5, 5, 6
```

but when I run this, program find **first instance of *NODE  and calls readnode()** function, but **fail to recognize second instance of *NODE**.
m_File is ifstream object of the same class where readnode() is defined as the private function.

**readnode() :**

```
 void mesh::readnodes()
 {
 char c;                                              
 int id;
 float x,y;

   while(m_File>>id>>c>>x>>c>>y)
   {
    node temp(id,x,y);
    m_nodes.push_back(temp);

    // dummy string for reading rest of line. 
    std::string dummy;
    std::getline(m_File,dummy);

   }
}
```

Comment: Your while loop will not stop at the 2nd NODE. You need to read each line first, then compare to NODE, then parse it as sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why the unexpected exit?

```
while(m_File>>id>>c>>x>>c>>y)
{
    node temp(id,x,y);
    m_nodes.push_back(temp);

    // dummy string for reading rest of line. 
    std::string dummy;
    std::getline(m_File,dummy);
}
```

In the code above, `m_File>>id>>c>>x>>c>>y` used to read `id,x,y`, but after read the first couple of node lines, it breaks when `m_File>>id>>c>>x>>c>>y` failed, which may also change `m_File` state. As a result, `getline(m_File, s)` return false, which cause the unexpected exit.

#### Solution:

I didn't come across a solution based on your original program. But since you want to extract value from string, then **boost** may be a better solution, check:

```
while (getline(m_File, s))
{
    if (boost::to_upper_copy(s) == "*NODE") continue;

    std::vector<std::string> SubStr;
    boost::algorithm::split(SubStr, s, boost::is_any_of(" ,"));

    SubStr.erase(std::remove(SubStr.begin(), SubStr.end(), ""), SubStr.end());
    m_nodes.push_back(node(atoi(SubStr[0].c_str()), atof(SubStr[1].c_str()), atof(SubStr[2].c_str())));
}
```

#### Fetch result:

```
for (auto Itr : m_nodes)
    std::cout << Itr.id << "," << Itr.x << "," << Itr.y << std::endl;
```

> Output

```
1,1.0,2.0
2,2.6,3.4
3,3.4,5.6
4,4,5
5,5,6
```

Comment: You figured out the mistake and it corrected my problem.

Comment: I'm glad it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for figuring out the error in the while loop condition in the readnode() function.
A better solution would be to change the readnode() function as below.

```
void mesh::readnodes()
{
char c;                         //temp.variable for recieving ','.
int id;
float x,y;
std::string temp;

// changes made in the while loop condition
while(m_File.peek() != '*' and m_File.peek() != EOF )
{
    //getline(m_File,temp);
    m_File>>id>>c>>x>>c>>y;
    node temp(id,x,y);
    m_nodes.push_back(temp);

    // dummy string for reading rest of line.
    std::string dummy;
    std::getline(m_File,dummy);

}
}
```